# Client Authentication in SSL Handshake

Tags: linux, openssl, ssl, certificates

I am trying to understand on how Client Authentication works during SSL handshake process.

1. Do we need to have Client Leaf certificate in Server truststore ? Is it referred anytime during Handshake process during two way SSL ? What if it is present, will it be ignored ?
2. In Server Hello message there is certificate_list message. This contains list of CA or Inter CA which would have signed client certificate. Clients will check this list and only send client certificate if its signed by CA or Inter CA present in the list. Is this understanding correct ?
3. Once Client send client certificate to Server , Server will check if its signed by Known CA (CA present in certificate_list in Server hello) , If it is then server is sure certificate detail (cn) in certificate is legitimate. However at this point Server is unsure if client has private key of the client certificate or not (Could be client has got client certificate through illegitimate way) hence server expect certificate_verify message from client. That message is signed by Private key of client and since server is able to decrypt that message through Public key of client (Which server received in earlier message through Client Certificate) Server can now confirm Client is what it claims to be. Is this understanding correct ?
4. What is the content of certificate_verify message ?
5. In this case how servers differentiate between clients. Does server checks client CN and accept and reject client based on that ? Without this Server will accept all client if they have legitimate certificate rigth ?

Comment: This isn't really an Unix or Linux question.  Maybe https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/48802/how-to-validate-a-client-certificate may help?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not about Unix or Linux - it's a generic mutual TLS question.